# Consecutive elements in a list

Tags: prolog, dcg

I'm blocking on a predicate to code in **Prolog**. I need to code that two predicates:

If I call : `u([a,b,c,d,e,f], X).` it will give `X=[a,b], X=[b,c], X=[c,d]` ...

If I call : `v([a,b,c,d,e,f], X).` it will give `X=[a,b], X=[c,d], X=[e,f]` ...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried coding either one of these? Please share the results so that we could help you correct your code.

Comment: For the first one, in this list, I'm trying to extract 2 first elements of L : `u(L,P) :- ([ [P,P] | L ], P).`
But ... I've got no idea, I think the solution is simple ... I need to use recursivity

Comment: Then you should unify `L` with a list `[First, Second | Tail]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although [false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false)'s answer is more elegant, here is a solution more appropriate for beginners for your predicate `u/2`.

```
u([X,Y|_], [X,Y]).
u([_|Tail], XY):- u(Tail,XY).
```

The first rule says that `[X,Y]` represent two consecutive elements in a list if they are the first two elements in that list.

The second rule states that two elements are consecutive in a list if they are consecutive somewhere in the tail of the list.

Now try to find a similar solution for `v/2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it works for V with another _ :) ... We got it !

Answer (score 4):

Assuming by `X=[a,b], X=[b,c], X=[c,d] ....` you actually mean
`X=[a,b] ; X=[b,c] ; X=[c,d] ; ...`, here is a solution using Prolog's [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)-formalism:

```
u(Xs, [X,Y]) :-
   phrase(( ..., [X,Y], ... ), Xs).

... --> [] | [_], ... .

v(Xs, [X,Y]) :-
   phrase(( evenell, [X,Y], ...), Xs).

evenell --> [] | [_,_], evenell.
```

Comment: The fact is that ... With 2 parameters that's not logical ... We are 5 friends trying to learn Prolog, our exam is in 2 days ... Please help us ...

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use append :

```
u(L, [A,B]) :-
    append(_, [A,B|_], L).


v(L, X) :-
     append([A,B], L1,L),
    (   X = [A,B]; v(L1, X)).
```