# Prefix in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, prefix

I'm new in Prolog.
I have a problem about predicate prefix but a little bit different.

I want to get a prefix of a list but until an element
The list can have repeat elements.

An example:

```
prefix(Element, List, Prefix)
prefix(c, [a,b,c,d,e,f], [a, b])
```

The element is not included.

What I have so far is this

```
prefix(X, [X|T], []).
prefix(X, [Y|T], [Y|Z]):-
    prefix(X, T, Z).
```

But it does not work.

```
L = [a,b,c] ? prefix(b, L, Prefix).

no
?-
```

Thanks

Comment: A right parenthesis is missing before ":-".

Comment: Please explain *does not work*.

Comment: What is the question mark in your last piece of code? It should be a semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`dif/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dif/2) you can explicitly state that for any member `X` preceding `Element`, `X \== Element`:

```
prefix(Element, [Element|_], []).
prefix(Element, [Head|List], [Head|Prefix]) :-
    dif(Element, Head),
    prefix(Element, List, Prefix).
```

or equally, because I wanted to use [`append/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) in the first iteration of my answer:

```
prefix(Element, List, Prefix) :-
    append(Prefix, [Element|_Suffix], List),
    maplist(dif(Element), Prefix).
```

For the suffix it is basically the same:

```
suffix(Element, List, Suffix) :-
    append(_Prefix, [Element|Suffix], List),
    maplist(dif(Element), Suffix).
```

If you don't want to use [`maplist(dif(Element), List)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/2):

```
all_dif(_, []).
all_dif(X, [H|T]) :- dif(X, H), all_dif(X, T).
```

Comment: One more question, if I want to do the same but starting from the last one, like suffix, how is it?

Comment: @Danick, it is basically the same if you use the `append/2` variant. I added it to my answer.

Comment: is there any way to implement it without maplist?  because we cannot use library

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using Definite Clause Grammars [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) and the non-terminal [`all_seq//2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24106828/772868):

```
prefix(X, Xs, Ys) :-
   phrase( ( all_seq(dif(X), Ys), [X], ... ), Xs).

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

So the grammar (within `phrase/2`) reads:

> There is
>    1. an initial sequence `Ys` with all elements different to `X`, followed by 2. `X`, followed by 3. anything.

There is still a downside, which is often the case when using DCGs: The implementation is not as determinate as it could be and thus leaves superfluous choicepoints around.

Comment: Your solution seems too complex for the OP purpose and level of skill.

Comment: @migfilg: You are free to give a less complex answer.

Comment: we cannot use complex solutions

Comment: @danick: yes, I would expect that. @false: The solution by @danick is almost ok for me, I would use a cut in the first clause to avoid for instance having a second wrong solution to `prefix(a,[a,b,a,c],L)`. I do not think I should post this as an answer.

Comment: @migfilg: cut??? I cannot see a clean use here (unless you put a lot of extra effort into)

Answer (score 0):

```
prefix(X,[X|T],[]).
prefix(X,[Y|T],Z) :- prefix(X,T,M)  , Z = [Y|M].
```

output:

> ?- L = [a,b,c,d,e,f] , prefix(d,L,G). 
> L = [a, b, c, d, e, f],
>  G = [a,
>   b, c] .
>
> ?- L = [a,b,c,d,e,f] , prefix(e,L,G).
>  L = [a, b, c, d, e, f],
>  G = [a,
>   b, c, d] .

**EDIT #1**
the original code is working , use (,) instead of (?) as following.

```
prefix(X,[X|T],[]).
prefix(X,[Y|T],[Y|Z]) :- prefix(X,T,Z).
```

output:

> ?- prefix(d , [a,b,c,d,e] , G).
>  G = [a, b, c]
>  
>   ?- L = [a,b,c] , prefix(b, L, Prefix).
>   L = [a, b, c],
>   Prefix = [a] .

**EDIT #2**
 as user [false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false) mentioned in comment, I can confirm that you are right, but in my solution, I assume that the list contains unique elements:
`prefix(d,[d,d],[d])` succeeds - it should fail ,

Comment: `prefix(d,[d,d],[d])` succeeds - it should fail.

Comment: Hope some up voting after I modified the answer ^_^ .

Comment: It looks still incorrect, you cannot add your own assumptions.

Comment: yes, false is right. And sorry didn't mention the list can have repeat elements. It should just give the first answer.

Comment: @Danick: You said "until an element". I cannot see any ambiguity in your original question.